# Changing date format in csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a stock market data set in 1 min time frame for 4 years. A row of 352000. The date format is in the following format

```
date        time
20130401    9:16
20130401    9:17
20130401    9:18
.
.
20130401    15:29
20130401    15:30
.
.
20160930    15:30
```

which I need to convert to 2013/04/01. I used this method:-

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime('20130401', format='%Y%m%d')

But all date format in row returns to 20130401. The date format is not changing respect to argument. please help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. SO is not a code writing service. Please provide what you have tried and a specific problem you ran into.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 df['date'] = df['date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

It's not really clear what datatype your date is in currently. This will only work if your date is currently a string. If it is not a string, you can change it by:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].astype(str) # convert to string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strftime` to transform `datetime` to your desired format.

**One liner solution**

If the date column type is `string`

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

If the date column type is `datetime64[ns]`

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

I'll advise you to read the [official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html).

Comment: It actually helped me to change the format. But the problem is date does not change respect to argument. If the argument is 20150731, it is still 04/01/2013.

Comment: @Khishor KS Please write your code segment in the question. And mention where are you facing the problem